# What is the relation between the first n digits of an exponentiation and the first m digits of its result?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Sorry if the title is not very explicit, but I really can't put it another way.

To clarify, how could I formally define the property where, e.g. $33^2 = 1089$ and $133^2 = 17689$,etc.. That is, for any number whose first 2 digits are $33$, squared, the first 2 digits of its square are always $89$.

This seems to be true for any $n^m$, where $n$ and $m$ are positive integers. Is there any theorem related to this that allows me to look at the first 2 digits of a number and figure out which were the first 2 digits of its n-root?

Comment: There seems to be some issue. for both examples you have $33^2$, but with different results

Comment: You must have intended $133^2$ for the second example.  Note that $67^2$ also ends with $89$, as do $17^2$ and $83^2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, indeed, I missed that, thank you!

Comment: When you say "first" do you mean "last"?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a theorem, but write your number as $$n=100h+r,$$where $r<100$. Then $$n^2=(100h+r)^m$$
You can now expand this:
$$n^2=(100h)^m+mr(100h)^{m-1}+...+mr^{m-1}(100h)+r^m$$
With the exception of the last term, all are divisible by $100$, so the last two digits are $0$. Then, when you sum together all the terms, the last two digits will be from the last term, $r^m$.

Answer (score 1):

I don‘t know if you‘re familiar with modular arithmetic, but if you analyse the situation mod 100, you can easily see that $33^2$ is congruent to 89 mod 100.

You can look at it this way: if you have a number ending in 33, you can write it as $100n+33$. If you now square this number you can see, that the n doesn‘t influence the first two digits of the answer and you get $10000n^2+6600n+1089$. So the first two digits are always the same, no matter what n you choose: 89.

Comment: Well, yes, but what if  what I want to know is the last 2 digits of the root, not the power? I only know the last 2 digits of the power and want to know which are the last 2 of the root.

Comment: I don‘t know what you mean exactly, but if you mean, that if you have a number ending in, say 89, you want to know what the last two digits of the root of that number are. Not every root of a number ending in 89 has the same last digits, most may not be perfect squares at all. EXAMPLE: if you have the numbers $289=17^2$ and $1089=33^2$, you can‘t know, by just looking at the last two digits of the number, what the root of those numbers ends in.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understood you want to find what the ending digits of a root of a given square (or given ending digits), I can recommend you to read this Wikipedia article about the topic (especially the “complexity of finding square roots“ part):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue

In there it is said that it‘s very difficult to find out whether there are solutions for any given two digit ending number (using the last two digits is like looking at it modulo 100, the article has the general case for any modulo n; it turns out to be more difficult to find these for composite n‘s like 100) and to compute those solutions. Although there are some fast algorithms using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).